# What does "being aggravated into the inquiry" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As a long and violent abuse of power, is generally the Means of
> calling the right of it in question (*and in Matters too which might
> never have been thought of, had not the Sufferers **been aggravated
> into the inquiry***) and as the King of England has undertaken in his
> own Right, to support the Parliament in what he calls Theirs, and as
> the good people of this country are grievously oppressed by the
> combination, they have an undoubted privilege to inquire into the
> pretensions of both, and equally to reject the usurpation of either.

I've been having issues to comprehend the statement inside parentheses.although, I know "aggravate" and "inquiry" mean "to worsen a situation,condition,..." and "an act of asking for information",respectively. But those two words here together don't make much sense to me.

[image: I've posted the entire page,in case the paragraph was not sufficient to get the gist]

Comment: Aggravated can mean annoyed or provoked.

Comment: Texts like this (apparently from the late 1700s) are not usually a good resource for English Learning.  The English is archaic.  If you are learning English, then find another resource.  If you are using English to learn history then [English.se] and [History.se] are better for you.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you sir.